# Cannot find module 'swiper_angular' on unit test (jest) after upgrading Swiper 6 to 7

Tags: angular, jestjs, swiper.js

I'm running into a problem on my unit tests after [upgrading Swiper 6 to 7](https://swiperjs.com/migration-guide). I'm using Angular 12 and Swiper 7.3.1. Before upgrading it the unit tests were working fine (Swiper version 6.5.9).

I'm using the `SwiperModule` in my tests like this:

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { SwiperComponent, SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular';

import { TeaserWrapperContainerComponent } from './teaser-wrapper-container.component';
import { InterfaceState } from '@migrosonline/shared-deps-all/core/interface/interface.store';


describe('TeaserWrapperContainerComponent', () => {
    let component: TeaserWrapperContainerComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TeaserWrapperContainerComponent>;

const mockedSwiperComponent = {
        swiperRef: {
            slideNext: jest.fn(),
            slidePrev: jest.fn(),
            destroy: jest.fn(),
            update: jest.fn()
        }
    } as unknown as SwiperComponent;

beforeEach(
        waitForAsync(() => {
            mockedInterfaceService.prototype.select = jest.fn();

            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [TeaserWrapperContainerComponent],
                imports: [SwiperModule],
                providers: [{ provide: InterfaceService, useClass: mockedInterfaceService }],
                schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
            }).compileComponents();
        })
    );

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TeaserWrapperContainerComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.teaserGroupSliderRef = mockedSwiperComponent;
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

and the error I get is this:

```
Cannot find module 'swiper_angular' from 'src/lib/shared/teaser/teaser-wrapper-container/teaser-wrapper-container.component.spec.ts'

      3 | import { of } from 'rxjs';
    > 4 | import { SwiperComponent, SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular';
```

I would appreciate any ideas/comments/suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case someone else run into this issue, the problem was related to the `eslint` or `tslint` configuration for the test and it got fixed adding the `swiper_angular` to the compilerOptions > paths in the `tsconfig.json` (or the `tsconfig.spec.json`) file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "swiper_angular": ["node_modules/swiper/angular"]
    } 
  }
```

I found the solution in the Swiper issues: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4315

Comment: I tried this method in my Nx monorepo app. It fixes the swiper_angular not found issue but introduces other fatal errors about  "libs cannot be found" when running the tests.

Answer (score 2):

to fix this you need to add the following to your jest.config.js file

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    'swiper_angular': '<rootDir>/node_modules/swiper/angular',
  },
transformIgnorePatterns: [
`node_modules/(?!(@angular|@testing-library|swiper|ssr-window|dom7))`,
```

],

swiperjs version: 8.3.2
angular version: 13

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble to import a module, just mock it in this way at the top of your test:

```
jest.mock('swiper/angular', () => ({
    SwiperModule: jest.fn(),
}));
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules

If you need to declare the SwiperComponent, just mock it at the top of your test:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'swiper',
    template: '',
})
export class SwiperMockComponent {
    @Input() pagination = false; // if pagination is needed
}
```

And declare it in TestBed or MockBuilder:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [SomeComponent, SwiperMockComponent],
    ...
});
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing your full spec file code? I am interested to learn about this method.

Comment: To mock a module, the test file must still be able to find its path.

Comment: Yes, but the module itself is not the problem here. The imports within the Swiper module cause this problem and therefore it is better to mock manually instead of adjusting (global) configs to get a test running.